# Does this cross-product norm inequality hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, cross-product

Let $\times$ denote the cross-product. $\;$ Is it the case that

> For all unit vectors $\:\mathbf{x}\hspace{.01 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{y}\hspace{-0.03 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}\mathbf{z}\:$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$, $\;\;\;\; \left|\left|\hspace{.03 in}\mathbf{x} \hspace{-0.03 in}\times \hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{z}\hspace{.02 in}\right|\right| \:\: \leq \:\: \left|\left|\hspace{.03 in}\mathbf{x} \hspace{-0.03 in}\times \hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{y}\hspace{.02 in}\right|\right| \hspace{.02 in}+\hspace{.02 in}\left|\left|\hspace{.03 in}\mathbf{y} \hspace{-0.03 in}\times \hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{z}\hspace{.02 in}\right|\right| \;\;\;\;\;$.

?

(If yes, then $\;\;\; \langle [\mathbf{x}]\hspace{.01 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}[\hspace{.02 in}\mathbf{y}] \rangle \: \mapsto \: \left|\left|\hspace{.03 in}\mathbf{x} \hspace{-0.03 in}\times \hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{y}\hspace{.02 in}\right|\right| \;\;\;$ defines a nice metric on the projective plane.)

Comment: Upon changing my simulation to require unit vectors, it seems like an overwhelming numerical yes. (Simulation is uniform from spherical distribution)

Comment: A rough guess of why this might be true. $|sin(\theta)|\leq |sin(\theta_1)|+|sin(\theta_2)|$ where $\theta=\theta_1+\theta_2$ if all three lie in a plane and $y$ is between $x$ and $z$. $\theta_1$ is angle btw $x$ and $y$. $\theta_2$ is angle btw $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Now think about the case, where $y$ lies above the plane, containing $x$ and $z$, then $\theta \leq \theta_1+\theta_2$  and it follows.

Answer (score 2):

Since they are all unit vectors, the cross product of any two is just the sin of the angle between the two, and is also directly proportional to the area of the triangle formed using the vectors as two of the sides. Therefore, it is equivalent to show that given a tetrahedron ABCD with ||AB|| = ||AC|| = ||AD|| = 1, [ABC] <= [ABD] + [ACD]. Now, there exists a line through A such that the projection of A onto a point A' in the plane containing BCD has ||A'B|| = ||A'C|| = ||A'D||. This projection also maintains the proportions between the areas of the triangles, and so it suffices to show [A'BC] <= [A'BD] + [A'CD]. Moreover, since the range of the cross product is [0, pi], angles BA'C, CA'D, and DA'B also fit into that range.

Now, let a = BA'D, b = CA'D, and so BA'C = 2*pi - a - b, and converting back from triangles to angles, it suffices to show sin(2*pi - a - b) <= sin(a) + sin(b), and thus only that 0 <= sin(a) + sin(b) + sin(a + b), 0 <= a, b <= pi. Moreover, sin(a) + sin(b) + sin(a + b) = cos(a/2)*cos(b/2)*sin((a+b)/2). Finally, since cos(x) is nonnegative for x in [0, pi/2], as is sin(x) for x in [0, pi], the inequality holds and we are done.

Comment: "such that the projection" orthogonally or along that line? $\:$ In the first case, I don't see how that line matters. $\:$ In the second case, it seems like it would be better to say "Let A' be the circumcenter of the triangle BCD." $\:$ In either case, I don't see why the projection maintains the proportions between the areas of the triangles. $\:$ Also, the range of the cross product is $\mathbf{R}^3$, not [0,pi]. $\;\;\;$

Comment: a) In general, the range of the cross product is not [0, pi], but since these are unit vectors, the cross product is equivalent to the sin of the "smaller" angle between the two vectors, and hence has the range is [0, pi].

b) You're right that I could have done a better job stating the importance of the line -- in retrospect I started with it because it was the inspiration when I originally solved the problem. To answer your question more specifically, you can use the law of sines to see why the proportion of the angles is maintained as A moves along the line to A'.

Comment: If you read the first three paragraphs in the definition it's much clearer: "The cross product is defined by the formula a x b = || a || * || b || * sin(theta) * n where ..."

Comment: "... $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector ..." $\:$

Comment: Perhaps this would take a bit more work, but since everything is a unit vector, we can abstract that away and only consider the sin(theta) part.

Comment: In that case, one would get [0,1] as the range, not [0,pi]. $\:$ Since exactly two of the side-lengths for each of the three triangles will also be changing and the remaining side-lengths will be different for each of those triangles, I don't see how to use the law of sines here. $\;\;\;$